# Android Studio layout editor does not show any suggestions

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-sdk-tools

I created new XML file `temp.xml`, when I tried to add text view in it, no suggestions are shown to me. When I clicked on TextView, TextView gets added with no body. Then I copy paste some code from other file and tried to give size, color etc to TextView editor is not giving me any suggestions(check image link below) I don't know is there any problem with my layout editor or with Android Studio. (I already tried Invalidate cache / Restart solution, not worked )
If you guys faced this problem in past plz help me. Thank You in advance.
This below image doesn't show any suggestions

[image]

Comment: show a screenshot of the error and also add temp.xml code

Comment: DO NOT add screenshots of code or errors. Paste it into the question

Answer (score 3):

There are three suitable answers for this question .

1. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart
2. Just navigate to your android studio installation directory, i.e

   ```
   yourDrive:/.AndroidStudio3.3/system
   ```

   and DELETE THE CACHE FOLDER ( first close android studio, if its running ).

   Then start Android Studio again. Done.

   P.S I am using android studio 3.3.
3. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run. Unchecked the box next to Restart activity on code changes.

Comment: @Robbit Happy to help!

Comment: how about windows ?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps (this will help you):

1) First of all, Invalidate cache and restart android studio.

2) Then delete .idea folder and all .iml files from the project.

3) Now restart studio again with invalidate cache.

4) Open your project and build.

That's it.