# "R" or "Resource" giving me error in Android Studio

Tags: android, compiler-errors

My problem is that whenever I add a new activity by its defaults, "R" just can't be recognized and giving me red color.
The first activity I added was LoginActivity, the ready to use template and no problems with it, and after that any other activity will give me the R error.
I tried "Clean Project" and "Rebuild" as most solutions say, but didn't correct it.
Is there something I'm missing?

The error is "cannot resolve symbol R", if you know it.
Sorry I couldn't upload a pic to make it clear.

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking.

Comment: Check this one..might help you...https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899288/5725622

Comment: Well, tried them but nothing changed, still same error. Luckily I'm just testing no so I'll try delete and reinstall Android Studio, that may helps.

Comment: @akhka Try to run check your build or message logs it will display the reason.

Comment: What version of Android Studio? What version of Android Gradle Plugin?

Comment: I checked everything, it's as I normally do nothing I've changed. Android Studio ver 3.3.2, and Gradle I guess just updated to 4.1 if not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Layouts and resources. When there are issues in resource it won't be able to build. It is one the reason you are getting Unrecognized **"R"**.

Comment: It's the default, and I assume that it easily would know the problem if it was from xml file, but it is R or the resource totally couldn't be recognized only in the new activity

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I just figured out that I only need to import the pakage for example for my project: com.example.apptemplate.R;

It didn't appear when I try "ctrl + insert" or "ctrl + enter", but I gave it a try and wrote it myself, and it's working fine.
Thanks for your help and efforts.